# Angular2/ASP.NET - "No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the URL"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build my own Angular 2/ASP.NET SPA on Visual Studio. You can find all the files [here](https://github.com/minusthebear/C_Sharp/tree/master/Test2/Test2).

What I tried to do is simple: after I followed the instructions to set up the app [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/), I began to add in my own files in an attempt to do some basic routing and I deleted some superfluous files. I have **ClientApp/app/app.module.ts** bootstrapping **ClientApp/app/components/app/app.component.ts**, and the only route is **ClientApp/app/components/app/test.component.ts**

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url "app.component.html"
at Object.get (C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17454:17)
at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13455:45)
at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13498:23)
at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective (C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13473:46)
at RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledTemplate (C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16869:210)
at C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16807:43
at Array.forEach (native)
at C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16805:50
at Array.forEach (native)
at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (C:\Users\Student\Source\Workspaces\mvs\Test2\Test2\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16804:45)
```

Everything looks right to me, but I'm new to both Angular 2 and ASP.NET, so I don't know if it is a compiler issue or human error. Here is some of the code, if you need more information the link to the repo is at the top of this question.

**ClientApp/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './components/app/test.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TestComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'test', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'test' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**ClientApp/app/components/app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**ClientApp/app/components/app/test.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    testing: String;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testing = "This Works";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `app.component.html` exist? You reference it in the code, but did you create it?

Comment: Yes, and it's in the same folder as app.component.ts

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this?  Running into the same issue w/ yeoman generated projects.

Comment: Mee too ..from a fresh installation of yeoman aspnetcore-angular2-spa

Comment: @LesPaul were you able to find a resolution for this?

Comment: Yes, your answer was correct. I figured it out on my own, but as you were correct you get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UniversalModule currently requires that external assets for templates and styles use require().

Try changing `templateUrl: './test.component.html'` to `template: require('./test.component.html')`.

And `styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']` to `styles: [require('./test.component.css')]`

More details on the issue can be found here: [Unable to load assets without using require()](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/333)

For reference, here is the issue thread from Angular on Github: [track runtime styleUrls](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/432). They recommend using the angular2-template-loader.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was I'm a webpack noob and tried to execute a `tsc` command which as per [Steve Sanderson](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1023#issuecomment-309790581):

> causes VS to spew garbage `.js` files all over your source directories...

The fix is to

1. Clean up any `*.js` and `*.js.map` files
2. Ensure `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` is true in the `*.csproj`
3. Try running project again

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs from `angular2-template-loader` with `SSR` and there are 
a couple of reasons why this issue appears:

- **Important**: Check if `angular2-template-loader` is up to date.

Usually, all the issues are related with @Component.

- As Will mentioned `-` in component name. (this has been fixed)
- Comments within @Component

Answer (score 0):

Check your webpack version (in a command line window, run `webpack --version`), if it's 1.XX then install the latest version of webpack 2 (2.2.X) and run it on the solution folder, and try again

Answer (score 0):

I run into this and in my case the problem was from an upgrade of angular2-templeate loader. The new version "0.6.1" caused this error to appear. I introduced the previous version "0.6.0" and everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the solutions above helped.  However, I had seen a mention in a [Steve Sanderson YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6MPSLgsGGs&t=616s) that **templateUrl:** (and **styleUrls:**) could be replaced with just **template:** (and **styles:**).  So, I took a shot in the dark. That fixed things for me and I was able to move on to the next hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the issue by removing the hyphen from component's name:
product-list.component  => wrong
productlist.component => OK