# No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url "xxx.component.html"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, angular, angular-cli

Just installed a new Microsoft template for Angular 4 framework with ASP.Net 2.0, there I installed Angular CLI by using the command:

> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Using Visual studio 2017 the first launch of the application was successful, but after I added a new component, I got the following error:

> No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read
>   the url "todo.component.html"

The todo component is as below:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html'
})
export class TodoComponent {
    public todolist: todo[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl +'api/todo').subscribe(result => {
            this.todolist = result.json() as todo[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
// 
interface todo {
    id: number;
    taskName: string;
    link: string;
    isComplete: boolean;
}
```

To try solving the issue, first I checked that `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` in the csproj file was set to true, then changed:

`templateUrl: './test.component.html'` to  `template: require('./test.component.html')`

with no luck, and no one of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797199/angular2-asp-net-no-resourceloader-implementation-has-been-provided-cant-re) worked

Any suggestions ?